# Complicate class for storing and calling a pointer to the static or member void function

Tags: c++

I want to write some driver to use a class below: but I can not understand the declaration of this class and how to use it.

```
typedef void (*pvoidf_t)(void);

/* A class for storing and calling a pointer to a static or member void function */

class FunctionPointer {

public:
    
    FunctionPointer(void (*function)(void) = 0);

    /** Create a FunctionPointer, attaching a member function
     *
     *  @param object The object pointer to invoke the member function on (i.e. the this pointer)
     *  @param function The address of the void member function to attach
     */
    template<typename T>
    FunctionPointer(T *object, void (T::*member)(void)) {
        attach(object, member);
    }

    /** Attach a static function
     *
     *  @param function The void static function to attach (default is none)
     */
    void attach(void (*function)(void) = 0);

    /** Attach a member function
     *
     *  @param object The object pointer to invoke the member function on (i.e. the this pointer)
     *  @param function The address of the void member function to attach
     */
    template<typename T>
    void attach(T *object, void (T::*member)(void)) {
        _object = static_cast<void*>(object);
        memcpy(_member, (char*)&member, sizeof(member));
        _membercaller = &FunctionPointer::membercaller<T>;
        _function = 0;
    }

    /** Call the attached static or member function
     */
    void call();

    pvoidf_t get_function() const {
        return (pvoidf_t)_function;
    }

private:

    template<typename T>
    static void membercaller(void *object, char *member) {
        T* o = static_cast<T*>(object);
        void (T::*m)(void);
        memcpy((char*)&m, member, sizeof(m));
        (o->*m)();
    }

    void (*_function)(void);                // static function pointer - 0 if none attached
    void *_object;                            // object this pointer - 0 if none attached
    char _member[16];                        /* raw member function pointer storage - converted back by registered _membercaller */
    void (*_membercaller)(void*, char*);    /* registered membercaller function to convert back and call _member on _object */

};
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Admittedly, the syntax of function pointers and especially member function pointers is... confusing at best. You can find some information [in this C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html).

Comment: template<typename T>
    FunctionPointer(T *object, void (T::*member)(void)) {
        attach(object, member);

template: I understand
typename T: I understand
T *object: I understand
T::*member: I don't understand this, I have never seen this declaration before. I try searching google and ask someone but in consequence, it's failed, nobody know it 

Can you explain and give one example to use this classs

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll address the comment:

```
template<typename T>
FunctionPointer(T *object, void (T::*member)(void)) {
    attach(object, member);
}
```

This part of the class declares a constructor template, similarly to a member function template. It's parameters are:

- a *pointer to an object of type `T`*, named `object`
- and a *pointer to a member function of `T` with no parameters and no return value*, named `member`

The syntax of the latter can be read as:

```
void   (T  ::  *  member)  (void)
^       ^      ^  ^        ^ argument list
|       |      |  | name of the parameter
|       |      | it's a pointer
|       | class type
| return type
```

---

Now, the rest of the functions:

```
FunctionPointer(void (*function)(void) = 0);
```

This is a (non-template) constructor with a parameter *pointer to a function with no parameters and no return value*, named `function`. The parameter has a default argument `0`.

The signature of the overloads of the member function `attach` can be understood similarly to the constructors.

`get_function` now finally uses a typedef: `typedef void (*pvoidf_t)(void);`, which defines an alias for the type *pointer to a function with no parameters and no return value*. This could have been done as well for the non-template functions (and constructors) of that class:

```
FunctionPointer(pvoidf_t function = 0);
```

This is an equivalent substitute for the declaration of the non-template constructor shown above.

---

The whole class is meant to store either a function pointer or a member function pointer. A pointer to a static member function is not different from a pointer to a free function, but a pointer to a non-static member function is: at the very least, it needs an instance of the class to act upon:

```
struct my_class
{
    int m;
    void set_m() { m = 42; }
};

typedef void (my_class::*mem_fun_ptr)();
mem_fun_ptr p_set_m = &my_class::set_m;

my_class instance;
(instance.*p_set_m)(); // we need an instance to call the member function
```

Therefore, when storing a member function pointer, the class `FunctionPointer` also needs to store a pointer to an instance.

A second problem arises because the *type* of the member function pointer is dependent on the class of the member function. The type of `void (class_A::*)()` is different from `void (class_B::*)()`.

From the function `membercaller` and the private variables, we can guess how these problems are solved in `FunctionPointer`:

- for any ordinary (free) function pointer, the data member `_function` is used
- for any member function pointer:

  1. data member `_object` is set to point to the passed instance
  2. the member function pointer is copied into a buffer (hopefully large enough), data member `_member`
  3. Data member `_membercaller` is set to point to an instance of the `membercaller` static function template. This is a crucial step: Inside the ctor/`attach`, we still know the class type of the member function pointer, but we lose this once we return. Therefore, the type is "encoded" in the instance of the `membercaller` template we point to. This function "knows" the class type because of its template parameter. For every different class type, a new `membercaller` instance is created, e.g. `membercaller<class_A>`, `membercaller<class_B>` etc. Those are different functions, with possibly different addresses and possibly different behaviour.
  4. data member `_function` is set to `0`

Further guessing: For any call, the member function `call` is used. If `_function` is not `0`, it directly calls `_function()`. If `_function` is `0`, it calls `_membercaller(_object, _member)`, which resolves to a call to an instance of `membercaller` with the "correct" class type for the member function call.

---

Two examples how to use this class:

```
void my_function() {
    // do something
}

FunctionPointer myptr(&my_function);
// store myptr, do something else
myptr.call();  // calls (indirectly) `my_function`
```

With a member function pointer:

```
struct my_class {
    int m;
    void my_function() { /*...*/ }
};

my_instance inst = {42};

FunctionPointer myptr(&inst, &my_class::my_function);
// store myptr, do something else

// make sure `inst` lives until after the call!
myptr.call();  // calls (indirectly) `inst.my_function()`
```

Comment: Thanks Sashkello so much
your explanation is so clear, I understand it and implement it successfully in my project
I extremely appreciate you and stackoverflow